# Design points of local polynomial regression

Tags: regression, nonparametric, asymptotics

Let the random set $\{(Y_{t},X_t)\}_{t=1}^n$ follow the model:
$$Y_t=m(X_t)+\epsilon_t,\quad t\in\{1,\cdots,n\}\quad (1)$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is a random error term and $m(\cdot)$ is an unknown smooth (conditional) regression function.

I have been reading papers on the convergence of nonparametric kernel estimators $\hat m$ of $m$. The results were stablished for random regressors $X_t$ (random design points). However, they apply their results for fixed design points such as $X_t=t/n$. **How can it be possible? What is the relation between $X_t\sim D(\cdot)$ and $X_t=t/n$?**

**Comments**

One of the authors [Kristensen, 2008, p. 6](https://repec.econ.au.dk/repec/creates/rp/08/rp08_37.pdf) explicitly said: "By defining $X_{i,n} = i/n \in \mathbb R$ (which for each $n\geq 1$ corresponds to i.i.d. draws from
a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$)". And then, he proves his theorem assuming $X_i\sim \text{i.i.d.} U[0,1]$ which is unclear to me.

In introductory textbooks, authors commonly treat both cases separately, and not as if the fixed design is a particular case of the random one.